# Heroku logs drain (stream) guidance

Tags: django, heroku, logging, stream

I have a simple Django webApp, which involves several workers as well, running related jobs at the background.

I would like to stream Heroku logs into the webApp for a dashboard view, so that users could track the workers progress within the webApp.

Ideally, I would like to access Heroku logs from the webDyno code, e.g. by some REST API, by some python library, etc. However, I'm not sure how to access the logs from the Django view (for pushing the content back to the Ajax caller).

As far as I know, the Heroku logs can be retrieved by either Heroku UI, Heroku CLI or Heroku Log-Drain (or by some 3rd party add-ons).

I think that Heroku **[Log Drains](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/log-drains)**, with Logplex, could address this feature, but I'm not sure how to technically achieve that behavior.

Which steps shall be taken for achieving the desired behavior, as described above?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that the best answer or not, but I've managed to workaround it by using Coralogix as a logging server.
I added Coralogix add-on to my Heroku webApp, so that Heroku loggings started to get drained into Coralogix.
Then, I was using Coralogix Elastic API for accessing the loggings with a simple REST API (from my Django backend).